# Uniform convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{nx^2}{n^3+x^3}$ on $\left [ 0, \infty \right )$?

Tags: real-analysis

How one can studies the convergence of the series 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{nx^2}{n^3+x^3}$$ to $ x \in \left [ 0, \infty \right )$ ?

Using $g(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{n^3+x^3} $, I can show that for $x \geq 0$
$$\frac{n}{n^3+x^3} \leq \frac{1}{n^2}. $$
Then, by the Weierstrass M-test, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{n^3+x^3} $ converges uniformely to $g(x)$ ?

Could we say the same thing, thus, to the $f(x) = x^2 g(x)$ ?

Comment: No, try $x=n$. $ $

Comment: @Did $x$ is fixed.

Comment: No, please reread the definition of uniform convergence.

Comment: No, the argument is insufficient.  You've proved that for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists a $N$ such that $\sum_N^\infty {n\over n^3+x^3}<\varepsilon$ uniformly for $x\geq 0$  When you multiply by $x^2$ you get a sum that's less than $x^2\varepsilon$ which doesn't help.

Comment: And about the uniform convergence of the series to $x \in \left [ 0,A \right ]$, $\forall A>0$ ?

Comment: @Did I know what uniform convergence is.  However, the sum is for a fixed $x.$  We have a function $F(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty{nx^2\over n^3+x^3}$  What can it mean to set $x=n?$

Comment: "I know what uniform convergence is. However, the sum is for a fixed x" Sorry but the second sentence seems to infirm the first...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't converge uniformly.  Suppose it does; then given $0<\varepsilon<\frac12,\ \exists N$ such that $$\sum_{n=N}^\infty{nx^2\over n^3+x^3}<\varepsilon<\frac12,\ \forall x\geq0.\tag{1}$$  Clearly, $$\sum_{n=N}^\infty{nx^2\over n^3+x^3}>{Nx^2\over N^3+x^3}\tag{2}$$
If we take $x=N,$ in $(2)$ we have $$\sum_{n=N}^\infty{nx^2\over n^3+x^3}>\frac12$$ in contradiction of $(1)$.

Perhaps this is what @Did meant in his comment.

Comment: Very good.

Thank you so much!

Comment: @CharlesFourier Glad to help.

Comment: One can omit the "Perhaps" (simply read said comment...).